# Can't import QtChart from PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyqtchart

This is the most weird problem I ever faced, I can't import QtChart from PyQt5 although I have it installed. I have tried a lot, but I can't figure out the actual solution. I have tried reinstalling multiple times. I have tried every single possible fix. But none helped.
And the most weird thing is, the import color is in yellow. Whenever I tell my code editor to import a wrong module, it becomes in white color ([See this image of my code editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTkRb.png)). But when I import right modules, it's yellow. Now for this case, it's yellow, but it's still saying can't import the module.

I get import error, Import "PyQt5.QtChart" could not be resolved from source (PylancereportMissingModuleSource)

The code I wrote:

```py
from PyQt5.QtChart import QCandlestickSeries, QChart, QChartView
```

Comment: what happens when you open a terminal and manually import this module? What error are you getting?

Comment: Sembai Norimaki I get import error, Import "PyQt5.QtChart" could not be resolved from source (PylancereportMissingModuleSource)

Comment: don't make a comment. Post the errors you are getting as properly formatted text. Also explain the different steps you made.

Comment: Did you try installing the library globally?

Comment: Yes I installed the library golablly

Comment: Please run that import command in an *actual* terminal/shell/prompt with the python interactive shell, not inside vscode, as you're probably using the wrong python interpreter there.